# Shared element end listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, shared-element-transition, sharedelementcallback

I use `addSharedElement()` with fragments, and I want to know if there are possibilities to add a listener to execute some methods after the end of this transition.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Fragment#setEnterSharedElementCallback(SharedElementCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setEnterSharedElementCallback(android.support.v4.app.SharedElementCallback)) does precisely that.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedElementEnd(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
               // transition has ended 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't find any methods which can help me. Could you please help me?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it